# Screen is only displaying the color white when building Qt android application that uses QML to Android x86 Emulator

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Below is the first 3 lines I get in Application Output whenever the android application starts to run in the emulator:

```
W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.Test/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libqtforandroid.so"
```

Also in compile output, I am having this warning after building the package/project.

```
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
```

It is my first time using Qt for android development.
Thank you in advance. :D